# Refresh image not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript

I am developing webcam application that display cam image on browser image refresh each seconds.  It works well in chrome while it do not work in other browser. below is java script code i used.   please suggest if anyone have solutions. Thanks in advance.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var access_point = "http://dogcity.viewmydog.com/cam0.jpg";
    function initCamera()
    {
        document.getElementById('main_image').src =access_point;
        setInterval(function(){refreshImage()},1000);
    }

    function refreshImage()
    {
        document.getElementById('main_image').src =access_point;
    }
</script>   
</head>  
<body onload="initCamera()">
<div class="innerDiv" id="innerDiv">
<img class="camImage" id="main_image" src="" width="320" />
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: *below is java script code i used* Where? Who ate that..?

Comment: Sorry Mr. Alien. missed to update code please help.

Comment: It's ok, and am not a JS-Fu but upvoted your question, so that it will atleast fetch you few question views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the variable `access_point` is not changed, I don't think that the browser will try to refresh the image. Try setting a dummy(or empty) URL before setting back the real one, to trigger the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code run ok. 
The thing is that the browser cache the images. So if a new image incoming with the same name you'll not see it changing.
You can concat a number to the image url or you can use no-cache.

Comment: Aric It's correct but access point http://dogcity.viewmydog.com/cam0.jpg do not support query string. i.e when i send dogcity.viewmydog.com/cam0.jpg?q=123 it return's nothing

Answer (score 0):

i worked on it.but i think you should get information regarding server.how they are processing request.so that you can request accordingly.
because i didn't find any way from browser end to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can force browser to refresh the image by passing an extra variable while giving the src of image

change your refresh function like this

```
function refreshImage()
{
    var mainimage = document.getElementById('main_image');
    d = new Date();
    mainimage.src = access_point + d.getTime();
}
```